# Trouble searching through each worksheet of a workbook

Tags: excel, loops, vba

The procedure below is intended to search through each worksheet of a workbook opened through a file dialog.  It then searches for a sentence and sets that row, then searches for values in that row.

After the file is opened it runs through each worksheet of the workbook, but is seems to being referring to the values that the workbook is opened on.  If opened on the coversheet the values from that sheet are referenced sometimes.

What am I doing incorrectly?
Sorry for the bad formatting.

```
`Sub FindPlanswGI()
 Dim wb As Workbook
 Dim wb1 As Workbook
 Dim ws As Worksheet
 Dim CRD As String
 CRD = FolderSelection

 Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(CRD)

 For Each ws In wb1.Sheets
Dim NHGI As Range
Dim MX As Range
Dim NH As Range
Dim LC As Long
Dim NHV As Range
Dim MXV As Range
Dim i As Long

Set NH = ws.Range("B:B").Find("Searching for this non sentence.")
Set MX = ws.Range("B:B").Find("Searching for this non sentence too.")

    If NH Is Nothing Then

    MsgBox "Not here" + ws.Name
    GoTo NextWSH
    Else
        MsgBox "here" + ws.Name + NH.Address + MX.Address
    End If
'i = 4 to LC
 'LastRow
Set MXV = Cells(MX.Row, 4)
Set NHGI = Cells(NH.Row, 4)
Set NHV = Cells(NHGI.Row + 1, 4)

    If NHGI = "N/A" Or NHV = MXV Then
        MsgBox "Here" + ws.Name + NHGI.Address
    Else: MsgBox "No" + ws.Name + NHGI.Address

    End If
NextWSH:
    Next ws
wb1.Close
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Cells assignments for the MXV, NHGI, and NHV ranges need the ws worksheet object. So:

```
Set MXV = ws.Cells(MX.Row, 4)
Set NHGI = ws.Cells(NH.Row, 4)
Set NHV = ws.Cells(NHGI.Row + 1, 4)
```